# How to get the sum of columns in an SQL table?

Tags: c#, sql, datatable

I am trying to add a footer row in my SQL table that shows the sum of each column after copying it from a `DataTable`, but I keep getting a value of -1 as opposed to the Total value as shown here, and then to get the percentage by dividing some of the columns by the calculated sum, my code is below.

Thanks in advance!

```
        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\evxaf4\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            // create table if not exists 
            string createTableQuery = @"Create Table [DesignQuantitiesTable] 
                    ( ElementType varchar(200) , GrossVol real, NetVol real, GrossArea real, NetArea real, percgrosvol real, percnetvol real)";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(createTableQuery, dbConnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();


            // Copy the DataTable to SQL Server Table using SqlBulkCopy

            using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(dbConnection))
            {
                s.DestinationTableName = "dbo.DesignQuantitiesTable";
                //foreach (var column in m_elementInformation.Columns)
                //    s.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());
                s.WriteToServer(m_elementInformation);
            }

            SqlCommand sumgvol = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(GrossVol) FROM DesignQuantitiesTable", dbConnection);
            double sumgrosvol = sumgvol.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlCommand sumnvol = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(NetVol) FROM  DesignQuantitiesTable", dbConnection);
            double sumnetvol = sumnvol.ExecuteNonQuery();


            SqlCommand sumgarea = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(GrossArea) FROM  DesignQuantitiesTable", dbConnection);
            double sumgrosarea = sumgarea.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlCommand sumnarea = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(NetArea) FROM  DesignQuantitiesTable", dbConnection);
            double sumnetarea = sumnarea.ExecuteNonQuery();


            SqlCommand sumrow = new SqlCommand("Insert into DesignQuantitiesTable ( ElementType, GrossVol, NetVol, GrossArea, NetArea) values ('"+ "Total" +"',"+ sumgrosvol.ToString() +","+ sumnetvol.ToString()+","+ sumgrosarea.ToString() +","+ sumnetarea.ToString() +")", dbConnection);
            sumrow.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlCommand percentgvol = new SqlCommand("UPDATE DesignQuantitiesTable SET percgrosvol=(" + "GrossVol/sumgrosvol" + ")"  , dbConnection);
            percentgvol.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlCommand percentnvol = new SqlCommand("UPDATE DesignQuantitiesTable SET percnetvol=(" + "NetVol/sumgrosvol" + ")", dbConnection);
            percentnvol.ExecuteNonQuery();


            dbConnection.Close();

        }
```

Comment: Where you get -1? Did you check direct in your DB if after the bulk copy you have any data in your table.

Comment: Are you able to validate that your data inserted with the bulk copy is actually in the table to be selected back out? What do you get running your select sum(...) sql directly against the database, without your code?

Comment: Yes, I have got all my data in the table by checking my DB, but didn't manage to get the right summation value (check out the attached pic)!

Comment: Didn't get what you mean @TylerLee

Comment: What have you tried so far? This information would be useful for anyone answering your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not get the sum of the columns you are querying by using the ExecuteNonQuery method - this returns the number of columns affected by a non-query command - eg Update & Insert. Your queries do not affect any columns, so -1 may be returned. (See [ExecuteNonQuery returns -1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514854/executenonquery-returns-1)).

As you want a single value back you should be using the ExecuteScalarQuery (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) - this will return an object which needs converting (casting will work here) to the correct result type.

Try this :

```
SqlCommand sumnvol = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(NetVol) FROM  DesignQuantitiesTable", dbConnection);
double sumnetvol = (double)sumnvol.ExecuteScalarQuery();
```

etc